# how to get logging output with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use the logging module in my python program, I want to get that logging output.I use `"python test.py > 1.txt"`,but just get `"print"` content.

```
import logging

print("_____________start___________________________")

logging.error("test1")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8pGo.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can log to a file like this. More on [logging in python](https://realpython.com/python-logging/)

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.warning('This will get logged to a file')
```

Answer (score 0):

To pipe just `stdout` to a file you can use the bash `>` operator. To pipe just errors to a file use `2>` instead of `>` (2 stands for `stderr`, nothing defaults to 1 which is `stdout`). You can do `>` to one file and `2>` to another, but to redirect them all to one file you can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` with this syntax:

`python test.py > 1.txt 2>&1`

Notice that the `2>&1` makes the `stderr` go to `stdout`.

Comment: thank u so much,i use "python test.py 2> 1.txt",get what i want